# in R return position of values in a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame with five columns of data and I want to find where numbers between 1 and 20 are located ( for example)
for a single instance I have used ( something I found on stack overflow)

```
Filter( function(data) length(data)>1, split(data$No., data$N1))$`1`
```

I am trying, as a start, to get the function to look for 1:20 in the column designated N1.
I have tried:

```
    data.occurence = NULL

for (i in min(data$N1):max(data$N1) ) {
    i = i
    data.occurence[i] = Filter( function(data) length(data)>1, split(data$No., data$N1))$`i`
    data.occurence[i]   
    }
```

which gives me nothing. I know that the "for" part 'works' - I was hoping to get data.occurence[1] with the ID of where values were found and so on for i = 1:20.
I would also like the function to be able to go through each of the five columns repeating the same search each time
example data:

```
      No.        dat N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 N6 BN
1    1994 2015-01-31  7 10 16 33 39 44 15
2    1993 2015-01-28  3  4 17 24 30 34 36
3    1992 2015-01-24  4  8 19 35 44 49 17
4    1991 2015-01-21  1  6 32 34 37 45 26
5    1990 2015-01-17 29 37 42 46 47 49  4
6    1989 2015-01-14 17 20 28 29 33 36 23
7    1988 2015-01-10 13 14 16 24 41 43 39
8    1987 2015-01-07  4  5 10 12 20 23 24
```

running:

```
Filter( function(data) length(data)>1, split(data$No., data$N1))$`4`
```

gives a result of id of rows which contain 4 in column N1:

```
[1] 1992 1987 1977 1961 1960 1957
```

Comment: Please show some example data and expected output

Comment: If you assign NULL to an object, you are erasing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
 lst <- lapply(paste0('N', 1:6), function(x)
        Filter(function(data) length(data)>1, split(data$No., data[x])))
```

#### Update

Suppose you want to subtract the "max" value of "No." from the "lst" elements

```
 mx <- max(data$No.)
 lapply(lst, function(x) mx-unlist(x))
```

Or

```
 lapply(lst, function(x) lapply(x, function(.x) mx-.x))
```

Comment: akrun. If I want to subtract the values given by your lapply from the max(data$No.) i.e. "how many observations ago" instead of the ID, how would I do this? I have tried placing -max(data$No.) within the apply , but get an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: As before, perfect. I need to think carefully how this all actually works. Quite difficult conceptually for me.

Comment: @user1478335 Just look at the `str(lst)`.  You will find that it is a nested list.  The `lapply(` will get into the first layer of list.  But, to get inside the nested one, you have to either unlist or use another `lapply`.  I think this will become easier if you created a nested-nested nested list and then try.